# R Markdown: Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : unable to load shared object

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

I'm having this error when I try to knit any r markdown file in rstudio. I even tried it with the default empty file, but it doesn't work. The output is this error:

```
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'H:/Dokumente/R/win-library/4/xfun/libs/x64/xfun.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  Zugriff verweigert
Calls: loadNamespace ... asNamespace -> loadNamespace -> library.dynam -> dyn.load -> inDL
Execution halted
```

("Zugriff verweigert" is german and means "access denied", idk why thats in german while everything else is in english)
Any idea how I can solve this?

I tried to knit the r markdown file as a pdf document but it resulted in the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. What worked for me was that I first uninstalled R and Rstudio after which reinstalled R and then reinstalled Rstudio and it worked for me. This made sure both R and Rstudio were using the same versions.